# Moving from individual templates to inline

Tags: angularjs

I am using templateUrl to display specific php pages in my webpage. Now I wish to scrap the individual php pages and display code with variables passed to it. What is the easiest way to get back to this?

```
var AppModule = angular.module('App', ['ngAnimate', 'ngRoute']);

AppModule.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        .when('/page:pageNumber', {
            templateUrl: function ($routeParams) {
                return '/app/..../assets/html/page' + $routeParams.pageNumber + '.php';
            },
            controller: "PageCtrl"
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: "/page1"
        });
});

AppModule.controller("ViewCtrl", function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function(event, current, previous) {

        ...stuff...
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use scripts via `text/ng-template`, which allows you to write your templates inline while declaring a url to access them by. The following code can go directly in your index.html, and if your config is set to show '/my-template.html', the inline template will be output right in the ng-view above it.

```
<ng-view />
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/my-template.html">
  template goes here
</script>
```

Then in your config:

```
.when('/', {
  templateUrl: '/my-template.html'
});
```

Here's a little more info from the Angular docs:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/script

And lastly, this technique is demonstrated in one of the TodoMVC examples for Angular:

View: https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/examples/angularjs/index.html

Config: https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/examples/angularjs/js/app.js